# Check if last update time is greater than 10 minutes

Tags: mysql, sql, database, time, operators

I have the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM event_incidents order by last_update desc limit 1;
```

What I want is to get the first row and check if the last_update time on that row is greater than 10 minutes from the current time.

Comment: Your question is vague.  You should include what you want *returned*.  What does it mean "to check"?

Comment: Sorry yes I was too vague, what I want is to get the first row and check if the last_update time on that row is greater than 10 minutes from the current time.

Comment: That is what my second answer is doing.

Answer (score 3):

You can try like this:

```
select * from  event_incidents   
where last_update >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE)
ORDER BY last_update desc
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using aggregation and a comparison in the `where`.  If you have an index on `last_update` then:

```
SELECT (case when MAX(last_update) >= date_sub(now(), interval 10 minute)
             then 'recent'
             else 'ancient'
        end)
FROM event_incidents ;
```

I'm not sure what you want to return, so I made up "recent" and "ancient".

Note:

If you just want a flag on a single row being returned:

```
SELECT ei.*,
       (last_update > date_sub(now(), interval 10 minute)) as RecencyFlag
FROM event_incidents 
ORDER BY last_update desc
LIMIT 1;
```